# MacOS X Randomly Logs out while working

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, user-account

A friend of mine experiences the following behaviour while using a macbook quite normally (no heavy loads, etc.). She is returned to her log in screen and apparently logged out, because after logging in again all applications are closed and sometimes work is lost.

- The problem happens approximately once a month for a few years now.
- The problem persists after updating to Maverick
- I would say there is no issue with a full disk or excessive RAM demands by the programs in use. (mostly browser, skype, etc

Comment: Please publish 20-30 lines of the Console messages at the time stamp in question. That will allow us to close examine the root cause for logging off.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, create a new user and check if the problem persists (you can transfer your files via the "for all users" folder in /Your Drive/Users

Answer (score 0):

1. Properly logout of your system by closing all the applications.
2. Shutdown and start your Mac again.

The issue will be resolved. It worked fine for me on a MacBook Pro.